# L5.5 : How to auto discover package?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to create package and I following this tutorial https://devdojo.com/blog/tutorials/how-to-create-a-laravel-package

I want to use auto discover the new feature of L5.5, how step-3 should be? (what I need to write on laravel's composer.json)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel’s custom package’s providers will be auto-discovered only if the package present in `vendor` folder, So for that we need to make our package installable via composer itself.

So we need to make our custom package should be installable via composer, for that set your applications composer file with **minimum-stability** as **dev** is must and **we have to configure custom packages path**.

```
"minimum-stability" : "dev",
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "./packages/suresh/calc/"
    }
]
```

once you done that your package can be installed using `composer require <vendor/package>`, then it will configure auto discover as per your packages settings. Get the sample configurations for your package,

```
{
  "name": "suresh/calc",
  "description": "This demo for auto discover providers in laravel with custom package",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Suresh Veluamy",
      "email": "sureshamk@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "minimum-stability": "stable",
  "require": {},
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Suresh\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  "extra": {
    "laravel": {
      "providers": [
        "Suresh\\Calc\\CalcServiceProvider"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

For more information, i wrote a post,  [check it out here](https://medium.com/sureshvel/laravel-5-5-custom-packages-with-autodiscover-the-providers-5772c60d847e)

Comment: this is package's composer.json, and what I need to write on laravel's composer.json?

Comment: No need to add anything in laravel's composer , but only autoload your package as mentioned in that tutorial

Comment: composer dump-auto : I only see fideloper/proxy and laravel/tinker

Comment: Thanks you are great, last night I follow https://medium.com/@lasselehtinen/getting-started-on-laravel-package-development-a62110c58ba1 do we need symlink?

Comment: Yeah, the symlink is a good option, by use of this we don't need to clone the directory once again while in development